# How to add a complex constraint on a Django Model?

Tags: django, django-models

Dashboards have a team and a user associated with them and have an is_default key. I want to ensure that the is_default key can only be set once as True for each user + company. The user should still be able to create an unlimited amount of is_default=False dashboards. I want to use Djangos constraints for this. However I don't know how to set those up. Here is what I tried so far:

```
constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user', 'company'], condition=Q(
            is_default=True), name='unique_primary_dashboard')
    ]
```

I also tried using the CheckConstraint but I couldn't figure out how to query for the right paramters. At the moment my code apparently restricts nothing.

Comment: Is it your idea to restrict user from changing default dashboard ever or to ensure that there is only one default dashboard for user and company?

Comment: They may change the default dashboard, but yes there should be one and only one default dashboard per company for each user.

Comment: Constrains is not what you are looking for then. There are different approaches. The simplest one is to invert is_default attr for all dashboard instances that user owns whenever it changed on one. It isn't the best way, but if you are sure that your app will never grow large then it'll work. Overwise you probably better store default dashboard in some kind of user settings model,  which is pretty resonable to suggest you will need in your project anyway at some point.

Comment: What is not working with the unique constraint? It looks that for each is_default, the user and company combination should be unique. It is however *not* said, that all databases will enforce these constraints. For examply MySQL 5.7 did not enforce such constraints.

Comment: @AlexeyPopov I don't want to introduce a new model and your rule just enforces that maximum 1 is_default exists, but there could also be 0.

Comment: Yes I have a local database, that could be it. Still this wouldn't make sure that the user always has exactly one is_default, right? It could also be 0, right? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @creyD: yes it could be that there are combinations where `is_default` is 0 for all user, company combinations.

Comment: But shouldn't this be a thing that is totally solvable with constrainst?

Comment: @creyD: if you can make database triggers, then yes, but with unique constraints and checkconstraints, no. Since check constraints only look at the record being manipulated, and unique makes something unique over all rows.

Comment: @creyD constraints have nothing to do with app logic, they just prevent creating/saving modelinstance with certain combination of fileds if another one already exists

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Normally I would do this by overwriting the save method or using the pre_save signal, but a CheckInstance sounds like it basically checks on save.

Comment: @creyD: it checks on inserts and updates, and has as scope only the row that is created/updated.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ah that makes sense. Thanks to both of you!